# I am writing a String to a text file. but null is getting printed

Tags: java, string, file, null

I have declared and initialed say a 
String temp = null;

through the program i am changing the value of temp by

temp = temp + folders[i] + newline;

and then write this String temp to a text file.

Now the issue is, every time I write it to the file, the word "NULL" gets printed too.

Please suggest me a work around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

initialize temp to "" instead of null

Comment: that's why SO exists! if you look through some of my questions, you'll see where I made similar goofs :^)

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = temp + folders[i] + newline;
```

is

```
temp = null + folders[i] + newline;
```

so it will print null in the file use "" instead